# Algorithm to sum to target using as many elements as possible

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of elements, each being a randomly generated number from 1 - 6. I want to form as many 6's as possible, using as many numbers as possible.

For example, from this list:

```
[4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6]
```

I will have five 6's here. Apart from the existing three 6's, I can form two additional 6's:

1. (3, 3)
2. (4, 1, 1) or (4, 2)

With the second case, combination (4, 1, 1) is preferred because it uses more numbers than (4, 2) does.

How do I write an algorithm which takes a list of numbers and **returns as many combinations of 6 as possible, using as many numbers as possible**?

Currently I'm starting with this approach: start with the largest number, then keep adding the next largest numbers until 6 is reached. But I realize this approach won't be able to select the most numbers for a combination.

======

Edit: once an element has been used in a combination, that element cannot be used again in subsequent combinations.

The most important objective is to form as many 6's as possible. The other objective (having as few left-over as possible) is secondary.

Comment: Are the indices of the elements important to conserve? If not, there's a simple.way to compute what you want.

Comment: Heavily related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: @KlemenSlavič: indices are not important. But once you used a number in a combination, that number cannot be used again for the next combination. Put another way, I want as few "left-over" as possible.

Comment: @Idos: Yes I realize this is a variance of the "subset sum problem". I'm not really looking for an "optimal" solution, just a reasonably effective one.

Comment: That's a qualification you should put in the question. The mechanics matter since perturbations can overlap.

Comment: @KlemenSlavič: thanks, I added that in based on your comment.

Comment: The objective is ambiguous. Given [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5] you can either pick [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] in which case you've used 6 numbers and generated one "6"; or you can pick [(1, 5), (1, 5)] in which case you've used less numbers (4) but generated more (two) "6"s.

Comment: If you want to maximize the number of 6 first of all, you can use greedy algorithm. If you want to minimize the number of not used elements, I think only brute force will work here. If you dont want "optimal" algo, you can always try a greedy approach.